# Is there pre-trained doc2vec model?

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

Is there a pre-trained doc2vec model with a large data set, like Wikipedia or similar?

Comment: I just wanted to add a link to other pretrained gensim models: http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/embeddings

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of any good one. There's one linked from [this project](https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec), but:

- it's based on a custom fork from an older gensim, so won't load in recent code
- it's not clear what parameters or data it was trained with, and the associated paper may have made uninformed choices about the effects of parameters
- it doesn't appear to be the right size to include actual doc-vectors for either Wikipedia articles (4-million-plus) or article paragraphs (tens-of-millions), or a significant number of word-vectors, so it's unclear what's been discarded

While it takes a long time and significant amount of working RAM, there is a Jupyter notebook demonstrating the creation of a `Doc2Vec` model from Wikipedia included in gensim:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb

So, I would recommend fixing the mistakes in your attempt. (And, if you succeed in creating a model, and want to document it for others, you could upload it somewhere for others to re-use.)

Comment: I know this is a very old answer but do you think it is possible to train a Doc2Vec model on Google colab?

Comment: I'm not a users of Google Colab, but if I understand correctly that it lets you run Python code, in a notebook, with enough RAM to do common ML tasks – sure why not?

Answer (score 8):

Yes! 
I could find two pre-trained doc2vec models at this [link](https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec)

but still could not find any pre-trained doc2vec model which is trained on tweets